# Запуск процедуры в PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может одна и та же процедура в pl/sql выдавать разный результат? При первом запуске - получаем верный результат, при повторном же запуске в этом окне - получаем не верный.
Пробовали чистку cash, ставить commit (везде где можно), однако не помогло.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался и сможет помочь?

Comment: Если процедура не очень большая, приведите ее текст

Comment: Вообще говоря, я бы начинал не с чистки кэша и комитов, а с отладки процедуры и выяснения, откуда берется неправильное значение. `DBMS_OUTPUT`, пошаговая отладка, вот это всё... Как причину найдете, сразу понятно станет, что делать дальше.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема в том, что при дебаге не удается просмотреть выполнение процедуры из интересующегося пакета - нет видимо доступа. Надо отдавать на анализ разработке видимо

Answer (score 2):

Такое может быть, если внутри процедуры используется пакетная переменная. Переменная инициализируется при первом обращении к пакету в сессии. Потом, например, ваша процедура устанавливает новое значение переменной, и оно "живет" всю сессию. Коммит и кэш на нее не влияют. И это новое значение используется при вычислениях и дает ошибку.

Соответственно, у вас ошибка в коде, ее надо искать и исправлять.